# Clever or interesting or elegant or beautiful ways to write "80"

Tags: mathematics

A wonderful friend who is a maths professor, is turning 80 next month. He's just published his 22nd math textbook! [Prof John Vince.... his books are about math for computer graphics]
I would love to put some clever mathematical expression for "80" onto his cake. Could be an equation, a series, an integral, a summation.... anything mathematical really.

I got lots of inspiration from a question posed here  [6 years ago with a similar request for a 50th birthday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1061357/ways-to-write-50?newreg=3b7c2432a28c49c187cd19abd978a4d8). My math is good enough to adulterate some of these to apply to 80, rather than 50....

$$e^{\ln{80}}$$
$$160\sin{\frac{\pi}{6}}$$
$$40\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}$$
$$\frac{48s0}{\pi^2}\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{k^2}$$

.... but i'm sure there must be some elegant/beautiful 80-specific equations out there, such as this one that someone suggested for 50:

[$$\bbox[8pt,border:3px #FF69B4 solid]{\color{red}{\Large \lfloor e^\pi \rfloor + \lfloor \pi^e \rfloor + \lfloor \pi \rfloor + \lfloor e \rfloor = 50}}
$$](http://wolfr.am/24dbxKEa)

Multiplying this by 8/5 doesn't feel very elegant to me!!

I got so much wonderful inspiration from the previous question that I shall make a birthday card with all the different ideas, but the most beautiful will make it onto the cake.

Thank you for any and all ideas!

Comment: fun fact : your friend's age is actually 50 in hexadecimal

Comment: You can write it as 10, in base 80.

Comment: Or 2222, in base 3, or 88 in base 9.

Comment: "Clever", "interesting", and "beautiful" are not objective qualities. This isn't a puzzle, it's an open-ended, subjective, popularity contest. Voted to close.

Comment: We also have $80 = (3+1)(3-1)(3+i)(3-i)$.

Comment: Why was this question migrated? It feels like it would fit better on Math SE, ironically enough, as it's a open-ended math question with no pre-defined solution (unless there's a similar restriction on open-ended questions on Math SE, of course)

Comment: @samm82 It seems to be a unilateral decision of one of the moderators (Xander Henderson)

Comment: @samm82 Such questions are not, generally speaking, considered on-topic on Math SE.

Comment: @BenGrossmann It was not a unilateral decision---there was some discussion of it [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57688019#57688019).  However, only a moderator can migrate a question from Math SE to Puzzling.  I apologize if it was unwelcome.

Comment: @Xander more surprising than unwelcome I suppose. This seems like a perfectly fine recreational math/big list question

Comment: @BenGrossmann With respect to "recreational-math", I would argue that most questions which could be tagged as such might also reasonably be asked on [puzzling.se].  It seems that there is some overlap between the two sites. :D  As to "big-list", I think that there is an expectation that the content of the question and answers should allow for authoritative answers and shouldn't (in general) depend on an arbitrary constraint such as a choice of constant.  "How can I abuse operations to generate [n]?" doesn't really permit authoritative answers, and definitely depends deeply on the constant.

Comment: That is, if "How can I make 80?" is on-topic, why not "How can I make 42?" or "How can I make 2021?" or "How can I make 47?"?  These kinds of constraints seem (to me) more natural in a puzzling setting.  Of course, that doesn't imply that the question is any more on-topic on [puzzling.se] than on [math.se], and I have been duly chastened.  Again, I apologize for the misunderstanding (which is primarily on my shoulders).

Comment: Site policy should generally be enforced, but it should not override any clear signs of acceptance for a particular case. This post is, by a decent margin, the most upvoted question in the past couple of days, which means that the community has deemed it "on-topic regardless of policy", so I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: @Bass, the majority of the upvotes on this post are from Math.SE, not from here, because votes aren't reset on migrated posts. From memory, this was at about +12 or so at migration. Then, at least some upvotes are from HNQ visitors.

Answer (score 10):

Taking things in a different direction:
$$
80 = 8!!!
$$
Where $n!!!$ denotes a [triple factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial).

This is perhaps more comically presented as "I can't believe you're $8^{0!}!!!$"

---

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/80_(number)) has some interesting ones. For instance,

- $80 = \varphi(1) + \varphi(2) + \cdots + \varphi(16)$
- $80 = 2222_3$

Comment: What's also cool about 2222 in base 3 is that it's just one short of 10000.

Answer (score 5):

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$
$\def\e{\mathrm{e}}\def\W{\operatorname{W}}\def\Wp{\operatorname{W_0}}\def\Wm{\operatorname{W_{-1}}}\def\Catalan{\mathsf{Catalan}}$

This is a simple one:

\begin{align}   
(\sqrt[\e]{(\pi+\pi+\pi)^{\e+\e+\e+\e}}/\pi/\pi/\pi-\pi)/\pi
&=80
\end{align}

\begin{align}   
\left\lfloor \frac{\e^{\e\cdot\e}}{\e\cdot\e\cdot\e}\right\rfloor 
&=80
,\\
\left\lceil\frac{\pi\cdot\pi^\pi}{\sqrt[\pi]{\pi}}\right\rceil
&=80
,\\
\left\lceil\sqrt[\gamma]{\frac{\e\cdot\e^{\e\cdot\e}}{\e^\e\cdot\e^\pi}}\right\rceil
&=80
,\\
\left\lfloor
\sqrt{\e^{\textstyle\e\cdot\left(\pi^{\pi-\e}+\sqrt[\e]{\pi\cdot\frac{\pi}{\e}}\right) }}
\right\rfloor
&=80
.
\end{align}

$\endgroup$

Answer (score 4):

If you're willing to use the golden ratio $\varphi$ and the Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma$, I was able to come up with
$$\left\lfloor e^\varphi+\varphi^e+e^\pi+\pi+\pi e+e+\pi^e+\varphi^\pi+\pi^\varphi\right\rfloor+\lceil\gamma\rceil=80$$

Comment: There are plenty of ways to express $1$ besides $\lceil \gamma \rceil$, if one doesn't want to invoke the Euler-Mascheroni constant. For instance, $0!$ is a fun one.

Comment: If you’re adding 1 to a floored non-integer real number, why not just take the ceiling?

Comment: @Lawrence I just like gamma and I suppose I like the symmetry of having a floor and ceiling operation.

Answer (score 4):

Some more suggestions:

$$80 = 2^6 + 4^2 = 4^2 + 4^3$$

$$80 = \lceil 22^{\sqrt2} \rceil$$
$$80 = (1+2+3+4)\cdot5+(6+7+8+9)$$

Comment: At last one without floor or ceiling! Especially the 123456789 version (I plan to remember it for my 80th (in 2028))

Answer (score 2):

How about:

$$\lfloor e + \pi \rfloor \cdot \lfloor e \rfloor^{\lfloor e \rfloor^{\lfloor e \rfloor}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Well, not an answer, but rather an addition (i.e. a phrase which can be written on a birthday card for example) which is too large for a simple comment:

*Now it's time to start from a new line!*

Of course, this is a reference to the [ancient (but still existing in some contexts) limit of 80 character per line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characters_per_line). If your friend writes about computer graphics (and is 80 years old), he has likely seen and remembered those good old times when the programs were written on punched cards.

Answer (score 2):

Surprised no-one posted this one yet:

$$4e^\pi-4\pi = 80$$

(unless you make [rounding errors](https://xkcd.com/217/).)

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

$\lceil{e^{\pi}-\pi}\rceil \lceil{\pi}\rceil = (20)(4) = 80$

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that doesn't involve integer rounding

> $$\frac{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(\pi n)^2}}{\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{((2m-1)\pi)^6}} = 80$$